# Ошибка в пузырьковом методе c#

Tags: c#

Есть ступенчатый массив и его необходимо отсортировать методом пузырька. Код вроде потихоньку работает, но в один момент просто крашится, в какой именно не знаю, т.к. слишком много итераций. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
        int col = array.Length;
        int row = array[1].Length;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < col; ++k) 
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < row; ++l) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < row; ++j)
                    {
                        if ((i + 1 == col) && (j + 1 == row))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if ((j + 1 == row) && (array[i][j] > array[i + 1][0]))
                        {
                            temp = array[i][j];
                            array[i][j] = array[i + 1][0];
                            array[i + 1][0] = temp;
                        }
                        else if (array[i][j] > array[i][j + 1]) 
                        {
                            temp = array[i][j];
                            array[i][j] = array[i][j + 1];
                            array[i][j + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: А как определено понятие сортировки на "степенчатом массиве" ?

Comment: @MBo. Массив стУпенчатый. Необходимо отсортировать в порядке возрастания. Что непонятного?

Comment: @dadyaSasha нетривиальный массив, приведите пример такого массива!

Comment: ааа вы про матрицы... никогда такие массивы ступенчатыми не называйте, не понятно сразу становится

Comment: @Санаев: эм. В коде я вижу ступенчатый массив. Что Вам не нравится в определении?

Comment: Что такое ступенчатый массив, я представляю. А вот что для таких (и вообще двумерных) массивов значит "отсортирован" - понятие неоднозначное, это нужно чётко определить до решения задачи.

Answer (score 1):

> в один момент просто крашится

Вы попадаете в блок `else if (array[i][j] > array[i][j + 1]){ ... }` и вылезаете за границу массива.

И уберите, пожалуйста, два внешних цикла.

Answer (score 0):

```
int col = array.Length;
    int row = array[1].Length;
    int temp = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < col; ++k)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < row; ++l)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < row; ++j)
                {
                    if (l != j && k != i) {
                        temp = array[i][j];
                        array[i][j] = array[k][l];
                        array[k][l] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```